# Gstreamer: Signal RTP header extension to the payloader

Tags: gstreamer, rtp

I have an RTP streaming app which implements the following pipeline using the C API.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v rtpbin name=rtpbin \
videotestsrc ! x264enc ! rtph264pay! rtpbin.send_rtp_sink_0 \
rtpbin.send_rtp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5002 host=127.0.0.1 \
rtpbin.send_rtcp_src_0 ! udpsink port=5003 host=127.0.0.1 sync=false async=false \
udpsrc port=5007 ! rtpbin.recv_rtcp_sink_0
```

I want to add header extensions to the RTP packet; therefore I created an extension using the new [GstRTPHeaderExtension](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtplib/gstrtphdrext.html?gi-language=c) class introduced in GStreamer v1.20. I want to set the attributes of the extension (e.g. color space properties for the example below). AFAIU this should be done by providing those as caps to the payloader element. However, I can't figure out how I should provide these caps exactly. Do I need to use a `capsfilter` here or what is the right way? In the current state, I can send the RTP packets and see that the extension is added but can't set the attributes.

Related parts of the code are below:

```c
#define URN_COLORSPACE "http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/color-space"  

const GstVideoColorimetry colorimetry = {
    GST_VIDEO_COLOR_RANGE_0_255,
    GST_VIDEO_COLOR_MATRIX_BT601,
    GST_VIDEO_TRANSFER_BT2020_10,
    GST_VIDEO_COLOR_PRIMARIES_BT2020};

const GstVideoChromaSite chroma_site = GST_VIDEO_CHROMA_SITE_MPEG2; 

ext = gst_rtp_header_extension_create_from_uri(URN_COLORSPACE);
gst_rtp_header_extension_set_id(ext, 1);
g_signal_emit_by_name(videopay, "add-extension", ext);

// other element definitions, links..
videopay = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264pay", "videopay");

colorimetry_str = gst_video_colorimetry_to_string(&colorimetry);
// How to provide these caps to the payloader set the extension properties?
caps = gst_caps_new_simple("application/x-rtp",
                            "media", G_TYPE_STRING, "video",
                             "clock-rate", G_TYPE_INT, 90000,
                             "encoding-name", G_TYPE_STRING, "H264",
                             "colorimetry", G_TYPE_STRING, colorimetry_str,
                             "chroma-site", G_TYPE_STRING,
                             gst_video_chroma_to_string(chroma_site), NULL);
```

Answer (score 0):

The caps should be provided to the sink of the RTP payloader element using a `capsfilter` element:

```c
GstElement *capsfilt;    
capsfilt = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "capsfilter");
g_object_set(capsfilt, "caps", caps, NULL);
gst_element_link_many(videosrc, videoenc, capsfilt, videopay, NULL)
```

where `videosrc`, `videoenc`, `videopay` are the source, encoder and payloader elements, respectively.
Also, the `caps` should have a media type matching to the encoder element. E.g. `video/x-h264` if the encoder element is an instance of `x264enc`.
The payloader will try to automatically enable the extension with the attributes set in the caps by passing the caps to the extension, if [auto-header-extension](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtplib/gstrtpbasepayload.html?gi-language=c#GstRTPBasePayload:auto-header-extension) is enabled (set to true by default).

In a gst-launch pipeline, the caps are passed automatically when the header extension is inserted after the payloader.